# Binomial coefficients - order matters in one subset of events

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

Question from 'Introduction to Probability' by Blitzstein-Hwang:

> Two chess players, A and B are to play 7 games. Scores are: a win is 1 points, a draw is 0.5 points and a loss is 0 points. 
> a) How many possible outcomes for the individual games are there, such that A ends up with 4 points and B with 3 points? 
> b) Now assume they are playing a best-of-7 match, in which the match will end when either player has 4 points, or after 7 games, whichever is first. How many possible outcomes for the individual games are there, such that the match lasts for 7 games  and A wins by a score of 4 to 3?

My solution for a) is:

$$\Bigl(\Large_4^7\Bigl).\Bigl(\Large_0^3\Bigl)+\Bigl(\Large_3^7\Bigl).\Bigl(\Large_2^4\Bigl)+\Bigl(\Large_2^7\Bigl).\Bigl(\Large_4^5\Bigl) = \normalsize 350
$$
because these are the ways A would have 4 points and B would have 3 points, and the order does not matter. 
For b), however, I don't know what to do. I was tempted to just subtract 35 ($\Bigl(\Large_4^7\Bigl).\Bigl(\Large_0^3\Bigl)$) from the sum obtained in a) because the only case the match would not last 7 games is if A wins the first 4 matches - but this would not be correct because A can win e.g. the first 3 matches, then lose 3 and win the last, so it would still be 7 games with the score 4:3. So in the case of b) order matters (but only in the event of A winning 4 games). What is the solution to b)? (And is my solution to a) correct?)